# in linux, how to (quickly) get a list of all files in a directory - with their filesize

Tags: linux, filesystems, ext4

I need to get a list of all the files, along with their sizes, in Linux.

the filesystem is ext4, running over USB on a machine with very little RAM

the functions I'm using are these - is there a better technique?

```
a) opendir()
b) readdir()
c) stat()
```

I believe I'm getting hit pretty hard with the stat() call,  I don't have much RAM and the HD is USB connected

is there a way to say

"give me all the files in the directory, along with the file sizes?" - my guess is that I'm getting impacted because stat() needs to go query the inode for the size,  leading to lots of seeks?

Comment: you should ask your question on:http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

No, not really. If you don't want to hit the disk, you would need have the inodes cached in memory. That's the tradeoff in this case.

You could try tuning `inode_readahead_blks` and `vfs_cache_pressure` though.

Comment: crud. I was hoping for something like inode_stash_cached_length_in_directory_entry :)

Answer (score -1):

Use `cd` to get to the directory you want to get the size of the files and directories for, then type:

```
du -sh *
```

This will give you all the sizes of the files and directories.
The `s` gives a total for each argument, `h` makes the output human readable. The `*` means that it will show all the contents of that directory.

Type `man du` to find out more about the `du` command (`q` or `Ctrl-c` to exit)